# Getting Top 3 value for each ID

Tags: sql, database, hiveql

I trying to figure out if it is possible to pull up the top 3 value based on count for each id using HIVEQL. Below in the input and output as such:

Do I have specifically need to do some inner joins and would appreciate some hints

```
Input
[id]        [word]  [count]
B000JMLBHU  book    89
B000JMLBHU  read    83
B000JMLBHU  was     76
B000JMLBHU  story   54
B000R93D4Y  with    69
B000R93D4Y  book    61
B000R93D4Y  story   60
B000R93D4Y  was     57
B000R93D4Y  have    53
B001892DGG  was     68
B001892DWA  was     73
B001BXNQ2O  was     119
B001BXNQ2O  book    59
B001H55R8M  was     56
B001HQHCBQ  was     93
B001HQHCBQ  story   75
B001HQHCBQ  bella   61
B001HQHCBQ  with    59
B001HQHCBQ  love    58
B001HQHCBQ  zsadist 53


Output
[id]        [word]  [count]
B000JMLBHU  book    89
B000JMLBHU  read    83
B000JMLBHU  was     76
B000R93D4Y  with    69
B000R93D4Y  book    61
B000R93D4Y  story   60
B001892DGG  was     68
B001892DWA  was     73
B001BXNQ2O  was     119
B001BXNQ2O  book    59
B001H55R8M  was     56
B001HQHCBQ  was     93
B001HQHCBQ  story   75
B001HQHCBQ  bella   61
```

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using? OR are you using Hive?

Comment: Maybe it is be sufficient if you test whether window functions are available in your database system or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` function :

```
select t.*
from (select *, row_number() over (partition by id order by count desc) as seq
      from table 
     ) t
where seq <= 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

*To be clear this answer is specific to Hiveql and valid for Mysql 8+*

You could use [common table expression](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Common+Table+Expression) and [window](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics) function [rank](https://drill.apache.org/docs/ranking-window-functions/#rank()) to get top 3 results per id

```
WITH cte AS(
    SELECT *, 
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY count DESC ) rnk
    FROM your_table
    ORDER BY id
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE  rnk <= 3;
```

Comment: @HalkoKarr-Sajtarevic I have added answer for hiveql please see the reference links and OP tagged his question for hiveql

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [ROW_NUMBER](http://dwgeek.com/hadoop-hive-analytic-functions-examples.html/) function and include in the where clause `ROW_NUMBER` < 3.

Answer (score 0):

The `LIMIT` clause might be what you are looking for:

```
  SELECT id
       , word
       , count
    FROM whatever
ORDER BY count DESC
   LIMIT 3
       ;
```

See [this section](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/limit-optimization.html) in the MySql reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ORDER BY on your count column with DESC, and LIMIT 3, that's how you will receive the 3 top values